# How to prevent forms data to be lost when swapping between components(no refresh)?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm swapping between 2 components (both contains forms) but i want to keep data the user have written in the form(no submitting) even after swappong the component.
It works on simple html by exchanging between tabs

I'm trying to swap components based on a variable called "value" from the parent component.

The parent component html:

```
  <ul>
 <li class="nav-item"><a (click)="changeValue(1)">Dine In</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a(click)="changeValue(2)">Delivery</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <app-dine *ngIf="value == 1"></app-dine>
 <app-delivery *ngIf="value == 2"></app-delivery>
```

in the parent ts i made a simple cahngevalue function:

```
 changeValue(x){
    this.value=x;
}
```

the child components are just forms:
example:

```
<form>
<input type="text"> //if the user write anything here i want to swap components to the other child without losing data
</form>
```

Please help. And Thank you!

Comment: ngInit should resolve your logic, it seems

Comment: @Dalorzo how ?.

Comment: I am not sure. If i understand correactly. How is looking the lifecycle of component? If you change the component propably it destroy data after you swapping between. I mean if you are initiating the component life cyclehook firstly it will start with constructor -> ngDoCheck -> ngOnInit etc, if you are leaving the component, then it use ngOnDestroy. Everytime you swapping between components it will rerender it. You should store data somewhere like sessionStorage or in the state with NGRX. I can be wrong, but i am not sure what does it look like in your project.

Comment: I think you can solve it at the cost of stepping into the *low-level* side. You can use the API provided by [ViewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef). By using the `detach` method you can get a reference to the current component that is about to be taken out of the view, which means it will not destroy it. This implies that you will have to create your components programmatically, and not declaratively.

Comment: Another way is creating reactive form in the parent component with values for children components and send them by @Input(). In the child component you will change value of created form. After swapping between child components, data will be stored in the form of mother component.

Comment: Easy. Hide the inactive tab with CSS instead of ngIf that recompiles the component. use `[hidden]="value === x"` or a CSS class `[class.inactive]="value === x"`

Comment: @DavidMeza Thank You a lot! It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by using

```
[hidden]="value === x"
```

in component conditions instead of swapping it.